# Euclid's Algorithm Time Complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I have a question about the Euclid's Algorithm for finding greatest common divisors.

gcd(p,q) where p > q and q is a n-bit integer.

I'm trying to follow a time complexity analysis on the algorithm (input is n-bits as above)

```
gcd(p,q)
    if (p == q)
       return q
    if (p < q)
       gcd(q,p)
    while (q != 0)
       temp = p % q
       p = q
       q = temp
    return p
```

I already understand that the sum of the two numbers, `u + v` where `u` and `v` stand for initial values of `p` and `q` , reduces by a factor of at least `1/2`.

Now let `m` be the number of iterations for this algorithm.
We want to find the smallest integer `m` such that `(1/2)^m(u + v) <= 1`

Here is my question.
I get that sum of the two numbers at each iteration is upper-bounded by `(1/2)^m(p + q)`. But I don't really see why the max `m` is reached when this quantity is `<= 1`.

The answer is O(n) for n-bits `q`, but this is where I'm getting stuck.

Please help!!

Comment: It is not true that `p+q` is halfed at a step. Consider `p=199` and `q=100`.

Comment: I made some edits.

Comment: It is O (Log(min a, b ))

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/18473133/2290983

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time complexity of Euclid's Algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980416/time-complexity-of-euclids-algorithm)

Comment: @namesake22 Did I answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine that we have p and q where p > q. Now, there are two cases:

1) p >= 2*q: in this case, p will be reduced to something less than q after mod, so the sum will be at most 2/3 of what is was before.

2) q < p < 2*q: in this case, a mod operation will be like subtracting q from p, so again the overall sum will be at most 2/3 of what is was before.

Therefore, in each step this sum will be 2/3 of the last sum. Since your numbers are n bits the magnitude of the sum is 2^{n+1}; so, with log 2^{n+1} (base 3/2) steps which is actually O(n), the sum will be 0.